Single-User (no root access) X-capable build
So, my office uses a server for Cadence, namely CentOS Linux 7 (Core).  It's a tightly locked down machine with a great many users, VPN access only, yadda, yadda.  I don't have root access, and by God and J. Edgar Hoover, I never will.
The current Emacs version is fairly old, 24.3.1, and I'd like to have a working copy of 29.4, or even 29.1, on the machine.  So, being more or less able to fumble through basic tasks like makefiles and so forth, I downloaded emacs-29.4.tar.xz from the repository, and tried ./configure --prefix=/users/<username>/.emacs.d --bindir=/users/<username>/bin to get the ball rolling, and what, to my wondering eyes, should appear...
checking for libXaw... configure: error: No X toolkit could be found.
If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without an X toolkit, pass
  --with-x-toolkit=no
to configure.  Otherwise, install the development libraries for the toolkit
that you want to use (e.g. Gtk+) and re-run configure.

...but the lack of a sleigh, and several missing reindeer.
Later, even if I tried installing without the X toolkit, there are other missing items...
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
    libXpm libgif/libungif libtiff
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
To build anyway, give:
    --with-xpm=ifavailable --with-gif=ifavailable --with-tiff=ifavailable

I could go through with these exceptions and end up with Frankenstein-on-Wish, but is there some way that I can provide development libraries to the compiler in my user directories?  I could curl the files, I suppose, and somehow signal to GCC that the necessary materials are to be found elsewhere?  I wonder if anyone has experience with this.

It would be ... difficult. Probably the best way would be to build on a CentOS 7 system on which you can install whatever is needed, copy the executable to the locked-down machine and try it. It's probably going to fail because of missing runtime libraries, in which case, you'll have to redo the configuration and build on your machine to avoid those libraries, since you can't install them on the locked-down machine. Even so, it might not work: even a completely stripped-down Emacs will require some runtime libraries, so if those are not installed on the locked-down system, it won't run.

ldd on the executable can show you what libraries it needs, so at least you can check if they are available on the locked-down system, without the trial-and-error of copying the executable and running it. And if that system is not updated to the latest available libraries, you might end up in version hell. All in all, a talk with a sysadmin type is indicated.

sure. you can build all the X11 and image libs you want and install them in your user directory, and point ./configure to them when building Emacs. you could download and extract the relevant RPMs into your home directory and do the same.  all and all it's going to be a pain, and just to put lipstick on a pig. i agree w/ @NickD, find a sysadmin, and come up with compromise. a little sysadmin-approved-bribery never hurts either.

I would love to bribe the system administrator, like I did in my previous jobs, but... er... this system isn't up for modification.  It's one where our server has a lot of data that belongs to folks have less than zero sense of humor.  You know, the guys with the mirrored sunglasses who slowly call you 'Mister Anderson.'

How hard would it be to transfer this from another CentOS 7 core and then just copy over all the missing .so files and so forth into my user directories, then direct the binaries to look in the right places?  I haven't done C seriously in over fifteen years and I have forgotten basically everything, but spinning up my own CentOS 7 server is really not a problem.

It would be a protracted trial-and-error effort but, assuming you use the exact same versions of all the libraries in the two systems (in order to avoid version hell), it could theoretically be done. You need to understand shared libraries and how Linux deals with them. I don't think you need any C (except as background).

Alright, I'm spinning up a x86 CentOS 7 core in a virtualbox on one of my private machines.  I love kinky shit like this.  How do I credit you guys for the answer?  Also, any advice?  I've never done something this deep before, transplanting binaries and linked libraries across machines.
